# Autorun macro when opening workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro named "Lastrow" when the workbook opens, but when opening the workbook the following error occurs:

> Compile error: Sub or Function not defined.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Lastrow
End Sub
```

[image: Autorun code]
[image: The code that i want to run when the workbook opens]
[image: the error i am getting when the workbook opens]

Note- The vba code "LastRow" is working fine there is no issue only the autorun isnt working

Comment: where is your `LastRow` code placed ? regular module ? or worksheet module ? can you share the code there?

Comment: @ShaiRado In this particular case, it's better to use `Call` for removing ambiguity.

Comment: Did you spell it correctly?

Comment: Have placed it in worksheet module

Comment: And the spelling is also correct

Comment: Put it into a `module` instead of a `worksheet` and declare it `Public Sub …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your procedure `LastRow` into a `module` instead of a `worksheet` and declare it

```
Public Sub LastRow()
```

Then you can use it like

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    LastRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to be explicit, for instance, if the procedure `LastRow` is in `Module1`, you have to write `Module1.LastRow`.

Comment: It's not necessary to append module name. It's required if you have procedure with same name in different modules.